# Post build function to copy to Azure via ftp with WinSCP fails

Tags: azure, ftp, msbuild, winscp

I am trying to deploy a visual studio .Net web project to a virtual VM on Azure.

When I build my project, I get the error:

> The command ... exited with code 255

I have a post build function in which I try to transfer my project via ftp.
I tested the ftp manually and it works fine.

**post build function**:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
<PropertyGroup>
    <PathToWinSCP>"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe"</PathToWinSCP>   
</PropertyGroup>
<GetDate Format="yyyyMMdd">
    <Output PropertyName="DateString" TaskParameter="Date"/>
</GetDate>
<ConvertToAbsolutePath Paths="$(OutputPath)">
    <Output TaskParameter="AbsolutePaths" PropertyName="OutputPath"/>
</ConvertToAbsolutePath>
<Exec Command="$(PathToWinSCP) /script=$(OutputPath)Deployment\FtpDeployment.config /parameter $(OutputPath) /log=$(OutputPath)FtpLog-$(DateString).txt" />
</Target>
```

**FTPDeployment.config**:

```
option batch abort
option confirm off

open ftp://USER:PASSWORD@IP-ADRESS/

put %1%\*

rm FtpDeployment.config

exit
```

I'm very new to deployment and scripting, so I hope someone can help and explain to me why I'm getting this error.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you include a full error message (with a relevant context from the build output)?

Comment: Can you try to build using command line with verbose log output ? it may contains useful additional information. `msbuild project.csproj /v:diag`

Comment: You can also set MSBuild output verbosity in Visual Studio (Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions-Build and Run).